# How to send chat messages to individuals by email address using Google Chat API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-chat

**Some Context**
So, I'm developing a task that analyzes several groups of data from a website and then sends a notification to the person who is tied to that group of data. From the groups of data, we are able to retrieve the person's email address as well as their name and some other personal identifying information.

**The Goal**
All of these users are part of a the same Google group. What we'd like to do is send them (*the individual user tied to the data group*) the notification and relevant data as a Google Chat message—their primary form of communication.

**What I Understand**
The Google Chat API seems to have some cool HTTP API requests available for the purpose of chatbots, but after searching around and viewing their references, it seems that this API is not used as anything more than as a chatbot or similar. It seems to need webhooks or some sort of account ID in order to create a message to someone in particular.

**The Question**
So, my question is as to whether or not there is a way to use the Google Chat API to send a message to a particular individual in the workspace identified by their email address.

My particular instance uses python, but if there were code/concepts in another language or whatever, please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may find this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65496824/how-to-send-a-dm-to-google-chat-via-api-using-email-or-phone-number) useful. You are pretty much correct about how the API works. As described in the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/rest-api) about the Google Chat API, everything is done using bots.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate more. I have read your reference but still can't figure out how. Because the request needs `parent` parameter which is the space id. I checked using the `spaces.list` and it doesn't list all spaces. So how can I send it to a user using their email address?
Thank you